# How could I improve this "math problem generator"?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently coding a simple math problem generator for a friend and his son.

**The program is supposed to generate random problems with the operators + & - with a range of possible outcomes from 0-20**

Since I just started coding I looked up some languages that could fit this task. I ended up with JS and this is the code I got so far.

It seems to be running fine except for the fact that my "if - loop" just cancels the prompt of a problem if the value of the generated problem isn't >= 0.

```
function aufgabe() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var op = ["+","-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
  var ergebnis = eval(a + op + b);

  if(ergebnis >= 0) {
    return prompt("Wie viel ist " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
  } else {
    ergebnis;
  }
}

var questions = [aufgabe()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;

alert( "Du hast "+correct+"/"+total+" Aufagen richtig gelöst!");
```

Comment: What is your question?  "How can I improve this" is too vague.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all `IF` statement is not a loop ( for, while, do while  and others are loops ) . Not sure what you want to do in the `else` statement ? so if the value generated is not over 0, what do you want to do ?

Comment: This question is probably better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RussJ No it isn't. That's for improving the coding style of working code. This code isn't doing what they want.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want *is* a loop. It should keep generating a new `ergebnis` until it's at least 0, then it should return it.

Comment: Why is `eval` being used here?

Comment: @Barmar Hello Barmar! Yes that would be exactly what I am looking for as an outcome. I apologize for not formulating properly, I just joined SO and started Coding today.

Comment: @MihaiT Thank you for clarifying.

The `else` statement is supposed to rerun the function and generate a new problem until the outcome is atleast 0. Then it should return the `prompt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after a `while` loop to define a math question that will resolve as `>=0`.

So as soon as `ergebnis` will be defined and will hold a positive value, the `while` loop will end and the `prompt` will be shown.

Look for the [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) documentation.

```js
function aufgabe(){

  var a,b,op,ergebnis;
  
  while(!ergebnis || ergebnis<0){
  
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    op = ["+","-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
    ergebnis = eval(a + op + b);
  }
  
  return prompt("Wie viel ist " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
 
}

var questions = [aufgabe()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;

alert( "Du hast "+correct+"/"+total+" Aufagen richtig gelöst!");
```

Comment: This is great! I also understand the difference and function off `while` and `if` statements now.

Comment: Great! ;) Can you mark the answer as accepted (grünes Häkchen) ?

Comment: I now have the problem that, for him in order to be able to run it, I would recommend him to download RunJS but the `prompt`command only seems to work in a browser enviroment. I assume it's beause of the textbox that shows up in the browser but doesn't exist in Windows itself? What would be an alternative for `prompt` in this case?

Comment: In order that runs in a browser... Save it as an HTML file. Like `math.html` and the minimal would be content : `<html><body><script>.... Your script here ... </script></body></html>`. Then the kid can double click the file and it will run in a browser.

Comment: Another idea would be to post your script in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) and simply give him the link. That would allow you to improve the script while the link stay the same. Here is a starter for you: [Math on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JjbagZj?editors=0010).

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to generate numbers with minimum and maximum values. I have one below

```
getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
```

You can then use the function as getRandomInt(0, 20) to generate operand a. Operand b will be determined by operand b and the operation.

That means before generating operand b you should already have your operator. If the operation is '-' operand b would be getRandomInt(0, a).

This way the minimum value of the entire operation would be 0.

If you need more clarification. You can ask

Update:
A full example to test with

```js
function aufgabe(){

  var a,b,op,ergebnis;
  
  
    a = getRandomInt(0, 20);
    op = ["+","-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
    b = getRandomInt(0, op === "-"? a : 20)
    ergebnis = eval(a + op + b);
  
  return prompt("Wie viel ist " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?") == eval( a + op + b);
 
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

var questions = [aufgabe()],
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(Boolean).length;

alert( "Du hast "+correct+"/"+total+" Aufagen richtig gelöst!");
```

Comment: I don't exactly see how that would fit into the program. If I understand correctly, this function would be used to generate both `var a` and `var b` in my code? It seems to overcomplicate the process without real benefit.

Comment: It fits perfectly and has a linear runtime unlike an iterative process where the the runtime is unpredictable.

Comment: I've done the whole implementation as an update to help you understand better. And this implementation promises to be faster with predictable complexity as compared to the conditional iterative method